# MSBUILD fails for a WCF project with a reference to WCFExtras

Tags: wcf, msbuild

I can build locally with Visual Studio 2010, but our automatic builds fail reading metadata from WCFExtras.dll.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

http://wcfextras.codeplex.com/

```
 CSC : fatal error CS0008: Unexpected error reading metadata from file 'c:\Workspace\.unison\XXXXService\Lib\WCFExtras.dll' -- 'Record not found on lookup.'
     [exec] Done Building Project "C:\Workspace\.unison\XXXXService\XXXXService.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
     [exec] Build FAILED.
     [exec] "C:\Workspace\.unison\XXXXService\XXXXService.csproj" (default target) (1) ->
     [exec] (CoreCompile target) -> 
     [exec]   CSC : fatal error CS0008: Unexpected error reading metadata from file 'c:\Workspace\.unison\XXXXService\Lib\WCFExtras.dll' -- 'Record not found on lookup.'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

verify that don't exist mismatch of version framework, between your version framework of your assembly an version framework of your deployment environment

Answer (score 0):

I think I encountered this issue by having Project1 and Project1Console where I set Project1Console to output the assembly name Project1 so that i can get Project1.exe

I think things blow up from it trying to create Project1.pdb for Project1Console when the pdb was already created by Project1 and chaos.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
For me it was caused by 2 separate projects with the same name.
The naming collision caused run-time errors, which were fixed by renaming the first project (i.e. from `Configuration` to `ConfigurationProvider`).

However, after the rename I started getting the `Record not found on lookup` error.
It seems this latter problem emanated from the `AssemblyName` still being unchanged (remaining with the previous `Configuration` naming).

Changing the `AssemblyName` (under Properties->Application) solved this for me.

TL;DR - two projects had the the same `AssemblyName`.